# detect if a particular wifi network is within reach

Tags: ios, wifi, cfnetwork

I'm working on an app for a local exhibition and some of the content is restricted to only being available when being at the location.

**I wonder how one can detect presence of a particular wifi-network and connect to it. Any clues how to code it?**

I have tried [Snap by 9Bit Labs](http://www.9bitlabs.com/Snap/) which is a full blown port scanner, so it is possible to do it, but a full blown port scanner is probably overkill for my scenario. Only one name is to be searched for, e.g. "local-exhibition".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. There is no API in iOS that will allow you to connect to a particular WiFi network, that is under your user's control. A port scanner like Snap cannot help either, as it doesn't find WiFi networks, it just scans for hosts on the one that your device is already connected to.

Comment: too bad. I guess I will explore the host detection way then. Thank you clarkcox3.